# Getting webpack style loader to let me import css within my components

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm currently messing around with https://github.com/sahat/megaboilerplate and trying to get it such that I can `import` css from within my components.

Here's my config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './app/main'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
       {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      { loader: "style-loader" },
      { loader: "css-loader" },
    ],
  }, {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          plugins: [
            ['react-transform', {
              transforms: [
                {
                  transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
                  imports: ['react'],
                  locals: ['module']
                }, {
                  transform: 'react-transform-catch-errors',
                  imports: ['react', 'redbox-react']
                }
              ]
            }]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
    }
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        screw_ie8: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  );
}

module.exports = config;
```

As you can see from the original config:

https://github.com/sahat/megaboilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js

I've added:

```
test: /\.css$/,
use: [
  { loader: "style-loader" },
  { loader: "css-loader" },
],
```

But when I run the server, I get:

```
/megaboiler/node_modules/spectre.css/dist/spectre.min.css:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { /*! Spectre.css | MIT License | github.com/picturepan2/spectre */html{font-family:sans-serif;line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,footer,header,nav,section{display:block}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}figcaption,figure,main{display:block}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0;overflow:visible}a{background-color:transparent;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:objects}a:active,a:hover{outline-width:0}b,strong{font-weight:inherit}b,strong{font-weight:bolder}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}dfn{font-style:italic}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}audio,video{display:inline-block}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}img{border-style:none}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}button,input
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you applying it in your project? As in, how do you import your CSS stylesheet? Your CSS is being injected into your JS bundle it seems.

Comment: @AndrewLi just with a standard import a la `import '../../node_modules/spectre.css/dist/spectre.min.css';`

Comment: @bob_cobb what is your end goal? When you say "component" is it angular? React? Or what exactly? Generally, you dont use the keyword "import" unless it's a module or a static import. It all really depends on what is the end result you are expecting and why you need to import css in a "component"?

Comment: Try `import CSS from "...";`

Comment: @AhmedMusallam this is a React component. My end goal is to not have to import styles in my .scss files but instead in my .jsx components.

Comment: @AndrewLi I'll still run into the same error.

Comment: @bob_cobb it would really help if you have a sample github repo I can download and debug. Something really simple with one component and the same setup you have.

Comment: Try installing css-loader like this `npm install --save-dev css-loader` and in your webpack config `{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }`

Comment: @bob_cobb as far as I can see there's nothing wrong with your webpack config. 1. do you have both css-loader and style-loader installed? they don't seem to be a part of megaboilerplate. 2. try importing non-minified version in your component and add `minimize` option to the css-loader instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your `test: /\.css$/` is now.

```
use: [
  { loader: "style-loader" },
  { loader: "css-loader" },
],
```

Seems that you may miss some loaders which can handle your files correctly, remember each loader has it's limits what it can process.

```
use: [
  'raw-loader',
  'style-loader',
  'css-loader',
  'postcss-loader',
  'resolve-url-loader',
]
```